# Solve $x^2(y'+26)=y^2+xy$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I have to solve the differential equation $x^2(y'+26)=y^2+xy$ by applying the knowledge of knowing how to solve the following types:

- $y'=f(x)g(y)$
- $y'=a(x)y+b(x)$
- $y'=a(x)y+b(x)y^n$

So far I've done this:
$x^2(y'+26)=y^2+xy$ 
$x^2y'=y^2+xy-26x^2$ 
$y'=(\frac{y}{x})^2+\frac{y}{x}-26$ - a homogenous equation, $x\neq0$ 
Now let $z=\frac{y}{x} \Longrightarrow y=z.x \Longrightarrow y'=z+z'x$ 
Thus $z+z'.x=z^2+z-26$ 
$z'x=z^2-26$ 
$z'=\frac{1}{x}z^2-\frac{26}{x}$ - not a familiar type of differential equation

Now let $z^2=t \Longrightarrow t'=2zz' \Longrightarrow z'=\frac{t'}{2z}$ 
$\frac{t'}{2z}x=z^2-26$ 
As you can see, It's getting more complicated than it was at the start. What am I doing wrong? I am trying to bring the equation to one of the forms above, so that I can solve it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint**

Starting with $y=x\,z$, the equation becomes
$$x^2 \left(x z'-z^2+26\right)=0$$ Now, switch variables

$$\frac x {x'}=z^2-26 \implies \frac  {x'}x=\frac 1{z^2-26}$$

Comment: Aha. And now I should integrate both sides of this equation, shouldn't I? Thus, I get $\int{\frac{x'}{x}dz}=\int{\frac{dz}{z^2-26}}$. Did I understand your hint correctly?

Comment: @DanielHalachev. Yes, that's it !

Comment: Thanks. There is just one last thing - how did you get $\frac{x}{x'}=z^2-36$? I tried to find it out myself but I failed. It must be something obvious, which I can't see.

Comment: @DanielHalachev. $\frac{dx}{dz}=\frac 1{\frac{dz}{dx}}$

Comment: That's what I was asking for. Thanks for your patience.

Answer (score 1):

Indeed, $xz'=z^2-26$ is a separable equation, there is no need to switch variables.

Alternatively, recognize that this is a Riccati equation (first order, quadratic in $y$), so set $y=\frac{u}{v}$ and try to find a simplifying condition in
$$
x^2\left(\frac{u'v-uv'}{v^2}+26\right)=\frac{u^2}{v^2}+x\frac{u}{v}\implies
x^2(u'v-uv'+26v^2)=u^2+xuv.
$$
With the formulation of the solution as fraction of two functions a degree of freedom was introduced. This freedom can be "used up" in several ways, here the aim is to split the equation into parts that allow for further simplifications.

For instance, collect and split off all terms containing $u$, set their combination to zero, dividing by $u$ under the assumption $x,u,v\ne 0$,
$$
x^2(-v')=u+xv\iff x(xv)'+u=0.
$$
Then collect the remaining terms,
$$
x^2(u'+26v)=0.
$$
Insert one into the other
$$
\implies x(xu')'=26u
$$
The last equation is Euler-Cauchy with basis solutions $x^{\pm\sqrt{26}}$.
$$
u(x)=Ax^{\sqrt{26}}+Bx^{-\sqrt{26}}\\
v(x)=\frac{Ax^{\sqrt{26}-1}-Bx^{-\sqrt{26}-1}}{\sqrt{26}}
\\
y(x)=\frac{u(x)}{v(x)}=\sqrt{26}\,x\,\frac{Ax^{2\sqrt{26}}+B}{Ax^{2\sqrt{26}}-B}
$$

Comment: I don't know why but I noticed that I do it quite often. (mania due to age ?). Cheers

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It's well explained yet I can't use the formulas you mentioned because I haven't studied them yet. Still, your answer and the accepted answer give me a better understanding of differential equations than my teacher.